# Missing gem when running rake

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm using rbenv with Ruby 1.9.2-p290, Rails 3.1, and the database is MySQL.

When I try

```
rake db:create
```

I get the following error:

```
Could not find multi_json-1.0.3 in any of the sources
```

I've also tried `bundle exec rake db:create`.

My GemFile looks like this:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.0'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'json'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Comment: can you verify your rails and ruby version by posting the results of: `rails -v` and `ruby -v`

Comment: I did but someone has edited my question.

Comment: I get the error when I do a rake db:create not migrate

I have rubyversion 1.9.2-p290 and rails 3.1

Comment: I believe what ennuikiller is asking for is if you can verify *for certain* that those are the versions that are being run when you are in your project's directory. A lot of issues with things like RVM and rbenv stem from *thinking* you are using certain versions, when in fact, you are not.

Comment: from the top of my message..

I'm using rbenv with Ruby 1.9.2-p290, Rails 3.1, and the database is MySQL.

Answer (score 4):

Quite old, but in case anyone else comes across this and is looking for the *real* answer: upgrade your bundler gem.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, Smathy. Saved me a headache for sure. The command is `gem install bundler`.

Answer (score 4):

For me didn't work neither smathy and kalleth answers.

Always getting:

```
Could not find multi_json-1.3.0 in any of the sources
```

What it worked for me was deleting Gemfile.lock and running again bundle install

It installed a new version of multi_json:

```
Installing multi_json (1.3.2)
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem too with a Rails 3.1 application + rails engines .
`bundle exec rake -T` reported the error you're reporting.

What solved it for me was running the following command to tell bundler to install the gems to the local 'vendor/bundle' path within the application with the following command:

`bundle install --path=vendor/bundle`

After I did that, `bundle exec rake -T` worked correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and used Jorge's answer to get to my solution:

```
bundle update multi_json
```

This just updates multi_json, and not all the other gems, which would potentially happen when you delete the Gemfile.lock and run "bundle install".

Comment: Hey, that is a nice idea to just update a single Gem (and not the others). Will try that ...

Answer (score 1):

Always run your commands through  `bundle exec`. That way you ensuer that you load the correct environment which is expected by your app. Use it like:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Also make sure you have actually run `bundle install` to install all required gems and their dependencies.