# Gem installed but not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, jruby

I'm trying to create a database, but I keep getting the following error:

```
$jruby -S bundle exec rake db:create
[31mCould not find json-1.7.6 in any of the sources
[33mRun 'bundle install' to install missing gem.
```

I have run bundle install (including jruby -S bundle install). This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792080/ruby-gems-wont-load-even-though-installed) is leading me to believe that maybe there's a problem with my environment. But, after looking at my Gem path and Gem environment, I don't think that's the case.

Here is my Gem path:

```
["c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/shared", "c:/Users/Jesse Flores/.gem/jruby/1.9"]
```

And my Gem Environment

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.24
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-02-21 patchlevel 385) [java]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/shared
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: c:/jruby-1.7.3/bin/jruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: c:/jruby-1.7.3/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-java-1.7
  - GEM PATHS:
     - c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/shared
     - c:/Users/Jesse Flores/.gem/jruby/1.9
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "install" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri --env-shebang"
     - "update" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri --env-shebang"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Also, I can see json-1.7.6 and json-1.7.6-java in my Gemfile.lock file.

Any ideas as to what's going on here?

Thanks!

Oh, I'm using Windows 8.

Comment: Can you see the gem in either folder of your gem path?

Comment: You can use `bundle show json` to see the full path for the gem and then browse to ensure everything looks right.

Answer (score 0):

As occasionally happens, found the right post that helped me solve the problem just a few minutes after posting the question.

Kaleth's answer on this post: [Missing gem when running rake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381407/missing-gem-when-running-rake) got me pointed in the right direction. With jruby, it's actually something like this:

```
jruby -S bundle install --path=vendor/bundle
```

After that, rake -T worked properly.